# How to map csv file to List<T>

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to read the content of the CSV file and map to `List<T>`
where `T` has the same column name with the file.

```
class InformationTypes{
    private String Title;
    private String Year;
    private List<String> Genre;
    private String RunTime;
    private String Rating;
    private String Votes;
    private String Director;
    private List<String> Cast;
}

private static List<List<InformationTypes>> allParts;
```

Here is how I tried to read and map:

```
listInformationTypes = Files
            .lines(Paths.get("imdb.csv"))
            .map(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(";")))
            .collect(toList());
```

It didn't work unfortunately. What am I missing here?

Sample data from file *imdb.csv*:

```
Title,Year,Genre,RunTime,Rating,Votes,Director,Cast,Gross

In the Heat of the Night,1967,Crime;Drama;Mystery,110,7.9,68739,Norman Jewison,Sidney Poitier;Rod Steiger;Warren Oates;Lee Grant,24.38

Forushande,2016,Drama,124,7.8,52643,Asghar Farhadi,Shahab Hosseini;Taraneh Alidoosti;Babak Karimi;Mina Sadati,2.4

Rogue One,2016,Action;Adventure;Sci-Fi,133,7.8,564143,Gareth Edwards,Felicity Jones;Diego Luna;Alan Tudyk;Donnie Yen,532.18
```

Comment: What didn't work? What was the result? You're splitting the row on semi-colon but specify "CSV" as the file format (comma, typically). Are you sure semi-colons are the delimiter in this file? CSV formats are a bit more complex than just "dump a value, add the delimiter" -- so this won't work for all CSV files.

Comment: Well, like I mentioned in my previous comment. You're splitting on `;` not `,` -- so there is one major issue. Another issues is that if the field contains a comma (it looks like the file is formatted so it may be less likely) then it will typically be quoted, which breaks down on simple `split(",")`. I'd recommend using or finding an actual CSV parsing library. Next, in your code snippet you're making no effort to take the split row and moving that data into the `InformationTypes` class so you will never receive a `List<List<InformationTypes>>` without modifying your `.map` closure.

Comment: Also, looking at your type and the file now I also noticed that you're 1) not considering the header row, and 2) the final output would be a `List<InformationTypes>`, your object seems to be defined to mimic a single row, not to represent each column in the row.

Comment: Your data is a mess with some delimiters being COMMA and others being SEMICOLON. Are those typos, or a screwball data structure?

Comment: @BasilBourque no, it is not a typo

Comment: @BasilBourque Nothing about that format means it's not CSV, it appears as if the semi-colons are used as sub-delimiters. For example the column "Genre" for "Rogue One" (last in the example) is `Action;Adventure;Sci-Fi` which likely means it belongs to 3 genres in the data set, but since the columns are delimited with a `,`, the generator of this CSV decided to use `;` for sub-lists. Nothing about that makes it "not a CSV" (also, technically tab-separated values classify as a "CSV" as the only change is the delimiter, the other aspects of the format typically remain identical).

Comment: @BrandonBuck You are right. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on using [streams](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html) then you basically need a mapper function to map each line of file *imdb.csv* to an instance of class `InformationTypes`.

In the below code, I use [record](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/language/records.html) (rather than class), simply to make people aware of its existence in Java since JDK 14. It simply saves you from writing methods such as `equals` and `toString` (among others).

Also note that I use [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) to call the *mapper* function from the stream handling code.

And I also changed the names of the variables, for example `Title` to `title`, so as to adhere to [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public record InformationTypes(String title,
                               String year,
                               List<String> genre,
                               String runTime,
                               String rating,
                               String votes,
                               String director,
                               List<String> cast) {

    private static InformationTypes mapper(String line) {
        String[] parts = line.split(",");
        String title = parts[0];
        String year = parts[1];
        List<String> genre = Arrays.stream(parts[2].split(";"))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
        String runTime = parts[3];
        String rating = parts[4];
        String votes = parts[5];
        String director = parts[6];
        List<String> cast = Arrays.stream(parts[7].split(";"))
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new InformationTypes(title, year, genre, runTime, rating, votes, director, cast);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Paths.get("imdb.csv");
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
            List<InformationTypes> allParts = lines.skip(1L)
                                                   .map(InformationTypes::mapper)
                                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
            allParts.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output I get when I run the above code using the sample data from your question.

```
InformationTypes[title=In the Heat of the Night, year=1967, genre=[Crime, Drama, Mystery], runTime=110, rating=7.9, votes=68739, director=Norman Jewison, cast=[Sidney Poitier, Rod Steiger, Warren Oates, Lee Grant]]
InformationTypes[title=Forushande, year=2016, genre=[Drama], runTime=124, rating=7.8, votes=52643, director=Asghar Farhadi, cast=[Shahab Hosseini, Taraneh Alidoosti, Babak Karimi, Mina Sadati]]
InformationTypes[title=Rogue One, year=2016, genre=[Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi], runTime=133, rating=7.8, votes=564143, director=Gareth Edwards, cast=[Felicity Jones, Diego Luna, Alan Tudyk, Donnie Yen]]
```

Comment: Records are Java 16+, not 14.

Comment: @BasilBourque not according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/records.html) for JDK 14.

Comment: You missed `gross`, the last field in import data.

Comment: @BasilBourque `gross` is not a member of class `InformationTypes` in the question.

Comment: Read further down on the page you linked: *Note: This is a preview feature*. Learn about preview features in [*JEP 12: Preview Features*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/12). The records feature was previewed in Java 14 & 15 before being finalized for official release in Java 16. See [*JEP 395: Records*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

Comment: "Gross" is the last header in the example data, and a field on the end of each example data row.

Comment: Good Answer. Would be even better, I think, if you used more specific types: `Year` for year, `Duration` for runtime, `BigDecimal` for rating and gross, `int` for votes.

Comment: I don't disagree that better types would be better overall but in the context of a Q&A site I think it's better to stick with (when possible) as much of the original code as possible. Which includes the types specified in the original question. I would agree that adding a note that using more specific types as values to the answer would be a good improvement.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create the object according the data schema of your csv, then convert the individual record into each object, which means each record is an object. Then you could read your csv through stream and save each record into a list. Rather than you read csv as string and save to list with your current solution.

If the code example needed, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question! Unfortunately, I feel like your answer is mostly restating what the asker has specified in their question. It would be great if you could provide more details to help clarify this answer and make it more useful (for the original asker and all other users who find it). It's also a bit unclear exactly what the problem is as the question has yet to clearly define the problem being encountered.

Comment: Ok. This is my first answer on stackoverflow even I have been 4 years here. I will provide more details asap.